# The effect of multiplication a matrix on the left on the kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix. Does multiplying $A$ on the left with an invertible $m × m$ matrix change the kernel of the associated linear transformation? Does it change the image?

I know that the kernel of the associated linear transformation does not change because if $Ax=0$. Then $M \cdot A$ preserves the row space of $A$ and the row space is perpendicular to the nullspace of $A$. Therefore, the kernel stays the same. However, it changes the image of the transformation because it doesn't preserve the column space of matrix A and only preserves the row space.

Is this correct? How do I prove this systematically using mathematical symbols?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying on the left by $M$ indeed doesn't change the kernel. This means
$$ Ax = 0 \Longleftrightarrow MAx = 0,$$
which is easy to show when $M$ is invertible (or generally when it is injective).

But it's easy to find examples where $A$ and $MA$ have different images. (Necessarily $A$ is not surjective -- why?) For example, take any $M$ that maps some vector in the image of $A$ to a vector not in the image of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If $Ax=0$, then $MAx=0$, so $ker(A) \subseteq ker(MA)$. This is true even if $M$ is not invertible.

If you further know $M$ is also invertible, then $MAx=0$ implies $Ax=0$ (multiply both sides by $M^{-1}$), so the reverse inclusion $ker(A) \supseteq ker(MA)$ holds as well.

In general, the image may change. For example, if the columns of $A$ are multiples of each other, then the image of $A$ is one-dimensional. Multiplying by an invertible $M$ will in general change this image to a different one-dimensional subspace.